# Custom CSS font won't work

Tags: css, fonts

For some reason the font I'm trying to add won't add itself to my website. I'd rather not do this with an image, so is it possible the font is broken? Would it be possible to fix it with just the otf or ttf?

My code (in case I'm missing something):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: urbanJungle;
    src: url('UrbanJungleDEMO.ttf');
}
h1 {
    font-family: urbanJungle;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #34495e;
}
```

Additional details: This is in the latest Chrome, other custom fonts work.

In the network console the font is red and it says cancelled.

Live URL: http://codestack.co.uk/website/

The font was from Dafont, no extra processing applied by myself, it's in the same directory as the index page. All the relevant CSS is included.

Comment: Use the 'Network' part of the console to see if the font is actually being loaded or not.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There’s a lot of data missing from the question, like the source of the font, how it was processed, all the relevant HTML and CSS used, preferably also a live URL demonstrating the issue

Comment: I flagged this question. Please give more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Font Squirrel font-face generator for this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Different browsers need different font formats, you only provided one. The generator will convert your font to all the formats needed and give you a CSS file too, with no hassles.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. And why all sites provide `ttf` which isn't displayed even in new Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You are using only TrueType font, IE support only *.eot fonts. And you are missing a lot informations. It is always better to use font stack instead of using single font, if first font went missing css use immediate next font on the list (called font-stack).

Here is an interesting article about @font-face by Paul Irish : [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

```
@font-face{
    font-family:MyFont;
    src:url(../font/MyFont.eot);
    src:local('?'),
        url(../font/MyFont.woff) format("woff"),
        url(../font/MyFont.otf) format("opentype"),
        url(../font/MyFont.ttf) format("Truetype"),
        url(../font/MyFont.svg#myfont) format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:normal;
}
body{
 font-family: "MyFont", Verdana, sans-serif; /* Font stack */
}
```